# how to access php defined constant using a $variable as the name of the defined constant

Tags: php

I have a variable defined using define()
I want to store a part of the name of that variable in a regular php $variable,
then access that defined variable by setting the name dynamically. ie.:

```
define('xxx_yyy',123);
$a='xxz';
$b='_yyy';


//How to I echo out "123" now?  (without using echo xxx_yyy);
//Something like these (don't work):
echo $a$b;
echo {$a$b};
```

The only thing I can think of is:

```
$defined=get_defined_vars();
echo $defined[$a$b];
```

but that seems clunky

Comment: wow! why? there has to be a better way- what do you want to achieve here? know what an array is?

Comment: want to achieve accessing a defined variable by assembling the variable name from other variables.

Comment: i cant imaging a scenario   where this is the ideal approach.

Comment: You should really look into PHP arrays. You can have an array store a bunch of variables and access them by key where the key is another variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo constant ( $a . $b );
```

is what i think you are looking for as it is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constant(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Answer (score 2):

It's not a variable, it's a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```
echo constant ( $a . $b );
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct function for this is **[get_defined_constants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)** and not **get_defined_vars()**.

Answer (score -4):

To make 123 echo out, use this:

```
echo $a . $b;
```

Also, define() makes constants not variables.

Comment: Erm... that would output `"xxx_yyy"`, not the value of that constant.

Comment: oops, i was just focusing on the concat